# $E[Y_n^{-1}]$ converges at the same rate as $E[Y_n]^{-1}$ where $Y_n = \bigg(n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 - \bigg(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i \bigg)^2\bigg)^k$

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, convergence-divergence, asymptotics, rate-of-convergence

Let $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n$ be i.i.d observations of a continuous random variable $X$. Let $Y_n$ be the sample variance:
$$
Y_n = \bigg(n\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 - \bigg(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i \bigg)^2\bigg)^k.
$$
Actually, for $k=1$, $Y_n$ is simply the sample variance scaled by $n^2$, i.e., we can write it as
$$
Y_n = n^2 \bigg(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 - \bigg(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i \bigg)^2\bigg).
$$

Here is a plot for the case of $k=1$.

[image]

From running computational simulations it is clear that $E[Y_n^{-1}]$ and $E[Y_n]^{-1}$ converge at the same rate as $n \to \infty$, e.g. there exists constants $C_1$ and $C_2$ such that
$$
C_1 E[Y_n]^{-1} \le E[Y_n^{-1}] \le C_2 E[Y_n]^{-1},
$$
for some constant $C$. In fact the simulations show they both converge as $O(n^{-2k})$. But how can we prove they have the same rate of convergence?

Comment: Notational note: You can write the convergence inequality as $\Bbb E[1/Y_n]\asymp1/\Bbb E[Y_n]$.

Comment: For the LHS inequality, I think Jensen's inequality may be appropriate. The RHS inequality seems trickier.

Answer (score 1):

For $k=1,$ we write $Y_n = n^2 S_n^2$ in the standard notation. Now, just forget about $n^{-2}$ (it will occur as it is in both $E[Y_n^{-1}]$ and $E[Y_n]^{-1}$). The rest should follow by applying Delta method with $g(x) = 1/x$ on the large sample CLT for $S_n^2$ which states that $\sqrt{n}(S_n^2 - E[S_n^2])$ converges in distribution to $N(0, \tau^2)$ for some $\tau^2>0.$

The same method should also work for any general $k.$

Fill in the details.